# Cannot find the declaration of element 'emp_comp'

Tags: web-services, xsd, xsd-validation

It seems that I am facing some problem while validating this XML

This is XML ,which I have created.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<emp_comp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/WebContent/XSD/Compensation.xsd">



<emp>
        <row_id>0</row_id>
        <emp_code>002</emp_code>
        <emp_compdt>01-04-2014</emp_compdt>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>Basic</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>100.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
    </emp>
</emp_comp>
```

Corresponding schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="emp_comp">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="emp" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="row_id" type="xs:int" />
                            <xs:element name="emp_code" type="xs:string"
                                minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="emp_compdt"
                                minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern
                                            value="|([0-3][0-9][\-](Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[\-][0-9]{4})" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="emp_cdata" minOccurs="0"
                                maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>

                                        <xs:element name="emp_cname"
                                            type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="emp_ccurr"
                                            type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="emp_camt" minOccurs="0" > <!-- ^\d+\.\d{0,2}$ -->
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" />
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Error which I am getting is Cannot find the declaration of element 'emp_comp'
what could be the reason for this.

Comment: You should remove the declarations on the header like this `<emp_comp>` and fix `<emp_compdt>01-APR-2014</emp_compdt>`

Comment: Ok, I see the problem with emp_compdt but what do you mean by "removing the header like this <emp_comp>"?

Comment: remove this declaration `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/WebContent/XSD/Compensation.xsd"`

Comment: but then ,how I will define the path to XSD?

Comment: By namespace and schemaLocation

Comment: can you refine my xml for me?, I am still a bit clueless. When I will see what changes you have made, I will understand what was the error.

Comment: You're not clueless at all.  You had almost everything correct except for a small mistake on `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.   See my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854978/290085).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

To:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Then, provided that you do really have your XSD at `http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/WebContent/XSD/Compensation.xsd`, it will work.  Pull it up in a browser to be sure.

Comment: thanks, other than this I need to write noNamespace as prefix of schemaLocation because I am not using any nameSpace :)

Comment: You're welcome, and I agree that you need `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, but your XML does already use it.  Once you fix the declaration of `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, your existing `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is fine (again, assuming that your URI is correct), and your XSD will be found.

Comment: Oh yes, one more error was there in path. I corrected that. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The problem is on first tag, remove this declaration `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/WebContent/XSD/Compe‌​nsation.xsd"` and and fix `<emp_compdt>01-APR-2014</emp_compdt>`

---

#### Possible Solution

Define a namespace on XSD `targetNamespace="http://namespace"`

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://namespace">
    <xs:element name="emp_comp">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="emp" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="row_id" type="xs:int" />
                            <xs:element name="emp_code" type="xs:string"
                                minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="emp_compdt"
                                minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern
                                            value="|([0-3][0-9][\-](Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[\-][0-9]{4})" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="emp_cdata" minOccurs="0"
                                maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>

                                        <xs:element name="emp_cname"
                                            type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="emp_ccurr"
                                            type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        <xs:element name="emp_camt" minOccurs="0" > <!-- ^\d+\.\d{0,2}$ -->
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" />
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

the XML could be

```
<ns1:emp_comp xmlns:ns1="http://namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://namespace http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/WebContent/XSD/Compensation.xsd">
    <emp>
        <row_id>0</row_id>
        <emp_code>002</emp_code>
        <emp_compdt>01-APR-2014</emp_compdt>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>Basic</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>100.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
    </emp>
</ns1:emp_comp>
```

Comment: No, we should be able to help OP without imposing a namespace on him solely for schema location.

Comment: @Xstian but I am not allowed to make changes in XSD :(

Comment: That's throwing io exception , I'll check that. wait.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this might be first I am answering my own Question

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <emp_comp  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost:9080/ermWeb/XSD/Compensation.xsd">



<emp>
        <row_id>0</row_id>
        <emp_code>002</emp_code>
        <emp_compdt>01-Jan-2014</emp_compdt>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>Basic</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>100.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>VPF</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>120.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>Employer NPS</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>130.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
        <emp_cdata>
            <emp_cname>Employee NPS</emp_cname>
            <emp_ccurr>INR</emp_ccurr>
            <emp_camt>140.00</emp_camt>
        </emp_cdata>
    </emp>
</emp_comp>
```

there were 3 errors as they are pointed out by other  answers.
1)01-04-2014 is incorrect, 04 must be replaced by APR
2)xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  , must add -instance in the end
and 
3) I need to use the XSD resource with the nameSpace ,to do that I have to add noNamespace before SchemaLocation in xsi:

Now XML is getting validated in accordance with XSD.

Comment: Congratulations.  Note, though:  **#2 [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854978/290085) your question.**   #1 addresses an additional error revealed after #2 allows your XSD to be found.   #3 is something that you're already doing properly because you're not using namespaces.